# How to get access to route id in data service

Tags: angular, angular-router

How can I get the access to the `localhost:4200/id` in data service to get it inside some JSON link?

I mean when I'm on localhost:4200/001 I want to get JSON of `zzz.com/001/summary`

Tried like that but in console appears that I've got `zzz.com/undefined/summary`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: ':id', component: AppComponent },
];

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService implements OnInit{
  baseUrl = 'https://zzz.com/';
  id :string;
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      const prodId = params['id'];
      this.id = `${prodId}`;

   })
  }
  mainData() {

    return this.httpClient.get<Header[]>(this.baseUrl + this.id + '/summary');
  }
}
```

I've menage to do it with: 
this.id =this.activeRoute.snapshot['_routerState'].url
and setting timeout inside onInit for 1ms. When I was calling it.

Comment: Where is `mainData` being called?

Comment: `Injectables` are just normal classes (normal objects) and as such, they have no special lifecycle.

When an object of your class is created, the class’s constructor is called, so that’s what your “OnInit” would be.

Comment: mainData is called in few components after the page is loaded

Comment: @PiotrKowalczyk, You should be sending the `id` from the place where mainData is called form.. That would be the right approach here.

Comment: It's still undefined, I mean id

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing the params/id to service from the component which calls it, that way you will have latest `id` to make the service call.

In Angular query params (Example: "/app?param1=hallo&param2=123") are accessed by subscribing to `this.route.queryParams`.

EX:

```
param1: string;
param2: string;
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    console.log('Called Constructor');
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.param1 = params['param1'];
        this.param2 = params['param2'];
    });
}
```

the path variables are accessed by "this.route.snapshot.params"

Example: "/param1/:query1/param2/:query2"

```
query1: string;
query2: string;
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.param1 = this.route.snapshot.params.query1;
    this.param2 = this.route.snapshot.params.query2;
}
```

Change the `mainData()` to accept a parameter:

```
mainData(paramId: string) {
        return this.httpClient.get<Header[]>(this.baseUrl + paramId + '/summary');
  }
```

Now use your component to access route params and get the id to make the service call.

```
this.dataService.mainData('123xx').subscribe.(data => {
      // ..... do something...
})
```

Comment: I've done what you've recomended but when I'm on http://localhost:4200/002 and I call in constructor console.log of pram1 I got undefined instead of 002.

Comment: I want by default it to be siteadress.com/:id maybe that's the issue I'm not redirecting it anywhere